# Отваливается файл CSS при попытке сделать загрузку jsp при деплое <load-on-startup> 1 </load-on-startup>

Tags: jsp, servlet

Файл index.jsp лежит в корне варника, нужно сделать так чтобы он загружался сразу при деплое, все работает только стили не подключаются, выводит чистый html

web.xml

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Index </servlet-name>
<jsp-file> /index.jsp </jsp-file>
<load-on-startup> 0 </load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Index</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Строкой `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` вы сами сказали контейнеру, что обработчиком всех путей (в том числе и css) является `index.jsp`. А не расскажете, зачем вам вообще понадобилось делать сервлет из jsp-файла?

Comment: Мне это нужно для того чтобы он загрузился первым, в jsp файле инициализируется класс шаблонизатора, в который передается сервлет контест. Если не прописать выше описанный код всё будет работать только при деплое нужно обязательно посетить эту стартовую страницу иначе компиляция не произойдет, не будет инициализации класса шаблонизатора и все остальные страницы будут показывать ошибку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для целей инициализации веб-приложения существует класс (интерфейс) `ServletContextListener`: вы создаёте свой класс, в котором реализуете этот интерфейс:

```
public class MyContextListener implements ServletContextListener {
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
    }
}
```

В методе `contextInitialized` можете делать вашу инициализацию. Затем добавляете в `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>my.package.MyContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Готово, теперь ваш код отработает сразу после загрузки веб-приложения (а если ваш код выбросит исключение, то приложение не загрузится).

Чуть не забыл: а фрагмент, который написан у вас в вопросе, после этого нужно удалить из `web.xml`.

Может быть, кто-нибудь ещё нас просветит, как это делается в servlet 3, там вообще не нужен `web.xml`.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/servlet/what-is-listener-servletcontextlistener-example/ Можно пометить аннотаций                                                                                                    Note
For Servlet container 3.x, you can annotate the listener with @WebListener, no need to declares in web.xml.